# my app don't scroll when i'm importing information in a component

Tags: react-native

my problem is that i'm importing some props by another js file but when i'm using it into a card created by ant mobile(but with every card i've tried is the same) my app doesn't scrolling, is like that she doesn't read the other cards created like true object, someone can help me please?

```
export default class Long extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { CustomData };
  } 
  render() {
    return(
      this.state.CustomData.map((cocktails, index) => (
        <View key={cocktails.id}>
        <WingBlank size="lg">
          <Card key={cocktails.id}>
            <Card.Header key={cocktails.id}
              title={cocktails.name}
              thumbStyle={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
              thumb="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/MRhHctKOineMbKAZslML.jpg"
              extra="this is extra"
            />
            <Card.Body>
              <View style={{ height: 42 }}>
      <Text style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}></Text>
              </View>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Footer
              content="footer content"
              extra="footer extra content"
            />
          </Card>
        </WingBlank>
        <WhiteSpace size="lg" />
      </View>
    ))
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [scrollview](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview)?

Comment: Wrap everything in a [ScrollView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview)

Comment: I've tried with only text and he scroll normally, if i try scrollview it don't make scrollable the page but every cards and it is useless, it gives this problem cause i'm using materialBottomTabNavigation from react navigation, i'm newbie so sorry if this is a stupid error